# Getting Correct ISO

Tags: server

The Ubuntu site looks clear when it says Download for different operating systems. I did this for Mac. When I looked at the file, though, it wasn't an ISO file. It was a "iso.download" file. And, when I looked at the size, it was 800ish KB. So, it wasn't just a file name issue. Why would Ubuntu not provide the ISO file itself on their website when you try downloading it? Can you direct me to a place I can download the actual ISO file?

Seems the Ubuntu website does not give links for the ISO file itself; rather, it gives Download Ubuntu links that provide some redirecting file that I can't use on Mac.

Thanks!

Comment: Providing the page you're using, as well as browser in use may help.  If I download a link I get only the expected file  (*but I usually avoid using a browser to download myself, using it only to find URL*).   I'd expect it to be a rename by browser for user-protection reasons, but your size implies it's not as you say.

Comment: Hmmm. Unable to duplicate the issue on the Ubuntu website. I click through the various download links and get a proper .iso download start every time.

Answer (score 2):

".download" is like a cache for the file that is being downloaded, perhaps you cancelled the download in the middle of it, make sure you let it finish, there's no better place to download an ISO than their official page.